# Run java process from Jenkins on remote host

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

I write Jenkins pipeline which in the end will trigger execution of java process on remote host. Currently this last stage looks like:

```
stage('end') {        
            sh '''
                ssh jenkins@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx java -jar /opt/stat/stat.jar
            '''
}
```

The process successfully started on remote machine but Jenkins job never ends. Is there any flag telling job must be completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like maybe your java command does not exit but stays running? And that's probably the desired behavior? What about putting the process in the background on the remote machine.

```
stage('end') {        
            sh '''
                ssh jenkins@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "java -jar /opt/stat/stat.jar &>/dev/null &"
            '''
}
```